# Pytorch: memory management

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, pytorch

Following [one code example by pytorch](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/actor_critic.py), I am interested in the following lines

```
del model.rewards[:]
del model.saved_actions[:]
```

I wonder when the user has to handle memory clean up and when he does not.

I am mostly interested in critical problems or memory leaks that could be caused by not managing memory correctly.

I am less interested in memory optimizations.

Comment: In the example, when a new episode starts, we don't want to keep around the rewards and actions for previous episodes. That's why they are deleted. This doesn't really have anything to do with cleaning memory

Comment: Yes, it's actually just a slightly convoluted way of writing `model.rewards.clear()`. The intent is to clear the rewards in order not to carry them over to the next episode.